# Django - generate product page with one url and view function?

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I have a list of products with product ids. How do i create the function to open the page based on the product_id and user_id?

Currently I have in urls.py:

`path('product/<int:product_id>/', views.product, name='product'),`

And in my views.py:

```
@login_required()
def product(request, product_id, user_id=None):
    return render(request, 'users/product.html')
```

I am new to Django and could not find an answer searching online...

Comment: The django tutorial covers your case [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/#raising-a-404-error).

Answer (score 0):

`user_id` will be automatically comes with the request object since you are using Django Session Authentication. There is no need to explicitly use in the url or view parameter. Also there is no need to use the `product_id` and `user_id` combinely, since I assume that `login_required` decorator used.

Your URL seems fine.

View should be like:

```
@login_required()
def product(request, product_id):
    context = {"product_id_variable_has_to_be_used_in_template": product_id}
    return render(request, 'users/product.html', context=context)
```